# Single URL for all Sub URL in PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html

I need that if the user is at `www.xyz.com/z` or say `www.xyz.com/z.trial.php` or say `www.xyz.com/offer.php` for all this the URL bar should show only and only **www.xyz.com**.

Yes, it's easy to have **iframe**, but `iframe` does not work for the URL copied and pasted manually in **URL** bar.

I will be thankful if someone provides me the hint for the code.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? Any chance to post a fiddle?

Comment: may be it is also known as shortened url

Comment: But then how will your application know what the user is requesting if everything directs to the same URL?  Do you always want to respond with the same page for every request?

Comment: No, it does not direct to the same URL, it is to be shown only in URL bar. I just do not want users to see `index.php` `offer.php` so on...

Comment: you can use dynamic urls to achieve what u want. by writing an .htaccess file and defining those url so that user doesn't know about source page

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule can I have a short clue/demo how to use that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly I understand what you mean. But it sounds like you want to mask the real URL for the user and always show just the domain? You simply can't. At least not while still letting them access a sub url directly as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson May be somewhat that only..

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that comment. Anyway, with rewrites in htaccess, you can only more or less create an "alias" of an URL. Ex: `/user/1234` internally accesses `/user.php?id=1234` and so on. You can't _change_ the URL in the users browser. If you _were_ to change it (like with pushstate in js), you would still have the exact same issue as with an iframe.

Comment: @Chiru check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781404/single-url-for-all-sub-url-in-php-html/45781662#45781662

Answer (score 1):

It is possible..
Suppose your directory structure is -

wamp/www/Project/.htaccess

wamp/www/Project/myproject

wamp/www/Project/myproject/file1.php

wamp/www/Project/myproject/file2.php

wamp/www/Project/myproject/file3.php

Your .htaccess file code

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

# Map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^myproject/sub1$ myproject/file1.php [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^myproject/sub2$ myproject/file2.php [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^myproject/sub3$ myproject/file3.php [nc,qsa]
```

sub1, sub2, sub3 can be changed because it is just for hiding the actual resource (php file / html file) from user

This concept is used in designing REST WebService using Core PHP.

You can also use it to any simple php project.
Just to hide actual resource location from end user's

Hope, it works for u.. :) :)

Comment: Please read the OP's question: _" the URL bar should show only and only www.xyz.com."_. This won't do that. This will still show a specific resource.

Comment: ya but only domain can't access the exact resources we have to pass some querystring like i explained it in above code snippet. Just to mask original URL

Comment: I know that, you know that but the OP doesn't. What the OP want's simply can't be done. At least not in the way the OP wants it. That's the actual answer to the question.

Comment: Ya, not exactly. But it seems that @Chiru wants something like dynamic uri only for masking urls. So, use of query string is necessary which will uniquely identify resources within a domain for mapping uri to find exact resource location

Comment: Seems this will help me out, but we have to code all one by one, or is there any way for all in one code

Comment: I used this
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

# Map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^web/sub1$ web/track.php [nc,qsa]

and my url has link
http://localhost/web/track.php
before and after

Comment: In your link 'Web' refers to 'Project' in my directory structure. So remove it from your rewrite rule. I have added sub-directory so that you can organize your code in hierarchical manner and apply rewrite rules to sub directories in your main project folder (in your case web).

Comment: just remove web from your rewrite rule just because your .htaccess file resides within that Web directory

Comment: like this :- RewriteRule ^sub1$ track.php [nc,qsa]

Comment: Ya.. you got it

Comment: So, I have to add codes one by one as I increase my `PHP` files or there is some way for one time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152425/discussion-between-chaitanya-ghule-and-chirag-jain).